# How do I use google fonts reliably with Mac version of Office 365 Word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, truetype-fonts

I would like to use some google fonts with an Office 365 Word document. I have a Mac OS version of Office 365. I understand the usual method is to set an option to embed font files when you save the doc, but [this Microsoft doc](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/07/06/document-font-embedding-demystified/) confirms that that isn't supported in Mac versions.

I can download and install the google fonts I want to use, of course, but if I send the document to someone who hasn't done that on their machine, I would think that the fonts would have to be embedded in the document for them to show up. Am I wrong, or is there no way to reliably use google fonts in a Word document generated with a Mac version of Word?